# CO2 kills humans. Does it also kill organisms?

Tags: biochemistry

CO2 kills humans.

Does it also kill organisms?
Does it also kill viruses?

Comment: I'm inhaling it right now and am still alive. The dose makes the poison.

Comment: Does an extreme does of CO2 kill viruses?

Comment: At what temperature and pressure?

Comment: temp: 98.6 --- pressure: 14.696 psi

Comment: Viruses are not quite alive in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Larger concentration of $\ce{CO2}$ directly affects only organisms with metabolism involving $\ce{CO2}$.

Killing is indirect as humans and animals fall into unconsciousness and stop breathing.

$\ce{CO2}$ is used, in mixture with $\ce{N2}$, as protective gas for packed food. It may not necessary kill bacteria, rather stops their growth.

A virus does not have metabolism, so it is not affected this way.

It **may** be affected indirectly as $\ce{CO2}$ dissolved in water causes mildly acidic environment.

In summary, $\ce{CO2}$ cannot be considered as desinfectant.